# How to connect SQL Server to Rust?

Tags: sql-server, rust, odbc, rust-warp

I'm new to Rust and have created REST API in Rust using Warp. I created a dummy grocery list API by following the tutorial from [LogRocket Blog](https://blog.logrocket.com/building-rest-api-rust-warp/) which uses local storage. Now, I want to add SQL Server to the code instead of local storage, but not sure how.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
use warp::{http, Filter};
use parking_lot::RwLock;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::Arc;
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use sqlx::mssql::{Mssql, MssqlPoolOptions};
use sqlx::Row; // Import Row trait for working with query results

// Other functions 

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // Initializing MS SQL Server database connection pool
    let db_pool = MssqlPoolOptions::new()
        .connect("my_connection_string")
        .await
        .unwrap();

    let store = Store::new(db_pool);
    let store_filter = warp::any().map(move || store.clone());

    let add_items = warp::post()
        .and(warp::path("v1"))
        .and(warp::path("groceries"))
        .and(warp::path::end())
        .and(post_json())
        .and(store_filter.clone())
        .and_then(update_grocery_list);

    let get_items = warp::get()
        .and(warp::path("v1"))
        .and(warp::path("groceries"))
        .and(warp::path::end())
        .and(store_filter.clone())
        .and_then(get_grocery_list);

    let delete_item = warp::delete()
        .and(warp::path("v1"))
        .and(warp::path("groceries"))
        .and(warp::path::end())
        .and(delete_json())
        .and(store_filter.clone())
        .and_then(delete_grocery_list_item);

    let update_item = warp::put()
        .and(warp::path("v1"))
        .and(warp::path("groceries"))
        .and(warp::path::end())
        .and(post_json())
        .and(store_filter.clone())
        .and_then(update_grocery_list);

    let routes = add_items.or(get_items).or(delete_item).or(update_item);

    // Add the cors middleware
    let cors = warp::cors()
        .allow_origin("http://localhost:3000")
        .allow_methods(vec!["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]);

    // Apply the cors middleware to the routes
    let routes_with_cors = routes.with(cors);

    warp::serve(routes_with_cors)
        .run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3030))
        .await;
}
```

Here is my cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "neat-api"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
warp = "0.3"
parking_lot = "0.11"
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
sqlx = { version = "0.5", features = ["runtime-tokio-native-tls", "macros"] }
sqlx-core = { version = "0.5", features = ["mssql"] }
```

Multiple errors were thrown, and it says that the `syn` crate cannot find specific modules, types, or macros being imported in the `sqlx-macros` crate. I'm not sure what that means.

the complete error log can be found [Here](https://justpaste.it/83zs3)

Any help will be appreciated, such as suggesting online articles or YouTube videos about connecting Rust to SQL Server. Thanks.

Comment: What issue are you facing here? Please provide details, or any error you are getting.

Comment: Hi @TanveerBadar, I've updated the question with the error that I've faced.

Comment: Post the actual error messages, rather than paraphrasing them. I think you'll also need to share thingsl ike your cargo.toml and other env details.

Comment: @TanveerBadar, Updated the question as you suggested!

Answer (score 0):

Found [ODBC](https://crates.io/crates/odbc), pretty simple and straight forward [*but it's very limited*] option currently available for connecting Rust to SQL Server.

Tiberius is an another option but it is not [maintained](https://github.com/rustsec/advisory-db/issues/261) anymore.
sqlx don't [support](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/issues/116) sql server yet. Wonder why the ecosystem of SQL crates lacks the support for MSSQL.